# Apache eChart disable the function of "dataZoomSelect"

Tags: echarts

I want to use the drag function for data zoom in echarts, but I want to fetch the data of the zoomed area from the server and draw it again when the data is zoomed.

Is it possible? Please give me any ideas. thanks.

Description:

1. When Drag area in the chart like below
   [image]
2. I don't want the chart to zoom like below. I want to fetch data and redraw chart.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of datazoom, use the brush tool to select a region, on brush end you can get the selected region and ask for the data and redraw the plot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the 'dataZoom' event and then pull additional data from your server.

```
this.chart.on('dataZoom', (params: DataZoomEvent) => {
  const options = params.batch[0];
  const startTS = options.startValue;
  const endTS = options.endValue;
  yourService.getData(startTS, endTS).subscribe(data => {
    // Replace the old data of your series by the fetched elements
    // If you reset the zoom, you will still have the detailed area
  });
});
```

The documentation about the event: https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.datazoom